# Search Results Web results how to make 2 dependent http request in different components in vue

Tags: http, vue.js

Search Results Web results how to make 2 dependent http request in different components in vue.

I want to fetch data from session and want to use the response in all other component requests in router-view. Couldn't find any way.

Comment: Hello! Please, provide us some example!

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand, do you want to make a session request and use the response in all components? This depends a lot on the structure of your project and its real objective, an alternative is to pass this data through [inheritance from properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) if this data is shared between parent and child components. if the data is shared between sister components or you need to use it in any application, I advise you to read the [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). To perpetuate these sessions so they are not lost, you can also use [localStorage](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html) to store the data.

Hope this helps.